# Convert latitude and longitude to Spatial Points and project them over another map in R

Tags: r, rgdal

I downloaded an SHP map of Mexico with all its states from an official government site. I also have a dataset with 300 weather stations and their coordinates. **I want to add these 300 stations to the SHP object.** However, my coordinates do not seem to be on the same geospatial region.

I read and plotted the Mexican map. Then, I turned the latitude and longitude of all 300 stations into Spatial Points. Unfortunately, I cannot spot the stations when I add them to the map.

Here's my code:

```
# Read official SHP map
Mex <- readOGR(dsn = "/Desktop",
               layer = "areas_geoestadisticas_estatales")
# Turn `stations` into Spatial Points and project them onto `Mex`
Geo_stations <- SpatialPoints(stations[, c("stations_lat", "stations_long")],
                              proj4string = CRS(proj4string(mex)))
# Plot `Mex`, then add `Geo_stations`
plot(Mex) 
plot(Geo_stations, col = "red", add = TRUE) # Nowhere to be found
```

In case you would like to replicate this exercise, [you can download the map here](https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/biblioteca/ficha.html?upc=702825217341).

This is a sample of my `stations` dataset:

```
    station_number station_lat station_long
 1:          10003      25.100     -106.567
 2:          10018      24.944     -106.259
 3:          10031      24.523     -105.952
 4:          10038      23.554     -105.411
 5:          10042      24.174     -105.967
 6:           1004      22.001     -102.199
 7:          10050      25.063     -106.531
 8:           1005      21.781     -102.372
 9:          10064      24.148     -105.953
10:          10087      25.129     -106.363
```

After comparing the results of `coordinates(Mex)` and `coordinates(Geo_stations)`, I realized that the "coordinates" of Mex are huge numbers, while the ones from stations look like actual geospatial references. I suppose I didn't project them correctly onto Mex. I expected `plot(Geo_stations, add = TRUE)` to add a layer of stations all over the country.

Comment: Your sample-stations seem to be missing a latitude coordinate? Also: better to provide data using `dput()`, so users don't have to retype/manually insert your data into R.

Comment: @Wimpel Yes. My bad! I updated the question. I had no idea about the `dput`function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

#load the shapefile
sh = st_read( "./702825217341_s/conjunto_de_datos/areas_geoestadisticas_estatales.shp",
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#set encoding of second column, because of the special characters used
Encoding(sh$NOM_ENT) <- "UTF-16"
#set crs of the current map
st_set_crs( sh, 5332 )
#transform to WGS84-coordinates
st_transform( sh, 4326 )

#let's see what we have so far
mapview::mapview(sh)
```

[image]

Looks ok.

Now you can add your stations to a sf-object and plot then into the map.

```
#sample stations
stations <- data.frame( station_number = c(10003),
                        station_alt = c(1754),
                        station_long = c(-106.567),
                        station_lat = c(26)
)

#make a sf-object out of them
stations <- st_as_sf( stations, coords = c( "station_long", "station_lat" ) )

#and plot
mapview::mapview( list( sh, stations ) )
```

[image]

Comment: And is the station now embedded to the map as a new layer or are they still two separate objects?

Comment: Also, were the stations not being plotted over my map because the CRS were different? I'm asking because I don't understand the `st_set_crs` and `st_transform` lines in your script. How did you know what CRS to set it to?

Comment: @ArturoSbr On the download page of your map, it says: `datum: ITRF08`, a quick google seach reveakls the crs code for that datum.... with `st_set_crs` you fill the crs for the loaded map... so sf knows what to transform FROM. With `st_transform`, you tell sf where to transform TO.